# Python argparse: Complex Argument Parsing Scenario

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to implement the following command line arguments parsing scenario:

I have 4 arguments: `-g`, `-wid`, `-w1`, and `-w2`.

`-w1` and `-w2` always appear together

`-wid` and `(-w1 -w2)` are mutually exclusive, but one or the other is required

`-g` is optional; if it is not specified only `(-w1 -w2)` can appear, but not `-wid`

Is there an elegant way to implement this using argparse, but without sub-commands (I am already in a sub-command)?

I was thinking of custom actions, but then in the body of the action I'd need to know when it is called for the last time (i.e. when the last argument is being parsed), which I do not know how to do since the number and the order of the arguments may vary.

Some more explanation just in case: the tool I am writing creates a gadget using a widget and a gadget parameter `-g`. The widget is either an existing widget - and then it is referred to by its id `-wid`, or a new widget that is created using parameters `-w1` and `-w2`. If `-g` is not specified then the tool will just create and store a new widget using `(-w1 -w2)` without creating the gadget.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if -w1 and -w2 always appear together, what reason do you have for having 2 arguments?

Comment: @mgilson: Actually, I've just being thinking about it: specify just one argument with nargs=2. Then create a mutually exclusive required group out of (-w1 -w2) and -wid. But I still have the last problem to contend with.

Comment: Have you looked at the docopt library?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, no, I have not. It does not seem to come packaged with Python 2.7

Comment: It's not in the standard library but you can install it with pip (`pip install docopt`). I always use docopt for building command lines applications.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, as I really do not want to re-write my existing code just for this purpose, I'll keep it in mind and try it the next time around. Unfortunately with Python one must often weigh the benefits of a non-standard package against the cost of installing it when multiple users/machines are involved.

Comment: @mgilson, specifying one argument with nargs=2 proved to be problematic. The first (minor) problem was that I could not give them separate names for usage/help purposes; the bigger problem was that they are of different types: one is a string another is a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose your defaults correctly, you can easily test for logical combinations of the argument values in the 'namespace' after 'parse_args'.  You can also issue a parser error at that time.  There is a bug report asking for mutually inclusive groups.  There I suggest a mechanism for adding generalized combination testing.  But it still requires your own logical tests.

http://bugs.python.org/issue11588
Add "necessarily inclusive" groups to argparse

The key to the solution I propose in that issue is making a `seen_non_default_actions` variable available to the programmer.  This is a list (set actually) of actions which have been seen (taking into account that optional-positionals are always 'seen').  I would like to see more discussion of how implement a mixture of inclusive and exclusive groupings.

You specify:

> I have 4 arguments: -g, -wid, -w1, and -w2.
>   -w1 and -w2 always appear together
>   -wid and (-w1 -w2) are mutually exclusive, but one or the other is required
>   -g is optional; if it is not specified only (-w1 -w2) can appear, but not -wid

Which I would attempt to summarize as:

```
complex_group('g', required_next_exclusive_group('wid', inclusive_group('w1','w2)))
```

`w1`,`w2` could be replaced with a `'--w1w2',nargs=2`.  A simple 'mutually_inclusive_group' would work here.  But `argparse` cannot handle nested groups.

`wid` and `w1w2` could be put in a required `mutually_exclusive_group`.

`-g` requires a test like `if args.g is None and args.wid is None: error()`

---

Here's a script which behaves as you require (I think), using my latest patch in Issue11588.  `act_w1` etc are the actual action objects, which may appear in the `seen_actions` list.  The test functions are registered with the subparser, and performed near the end of its `parse_know_args()`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='custom usage')
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
sp.required = True
spp = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
act_g = spp.add_argument('-g')
act_wid = spp.add_argument('--wid')
act_w1 = spp.add_argument('--w1')
act_w2 = spp.add_argument('--w2')

@spp.crosstest # decorator to register this function with spp
def test1(spp, seen_actions, *args):
    # seen_actions - list of actions that were seen by parser
    if 1==len({act_w1, act_w2}.intersection(seen_actions)):
        # error if only one of these was seen
        parser.error('-w1 and -w2 always appear together')
@spp.crosstest
def test2(spp, seen_actions, *args):
    # required mutually exclusive wid and (w1,w2 group)
    if act_wid in seen_actions:
        if act_w1 in seen_actions or act_w2 in seen_actions:
            parser.error('-wid and (-w1 -w2) are mutually exclusive')
    elif act_w1 not in seen_actions:
        parser.error('wid or (w1 and w2) required')
@spp.crosstest
def test3(spp, seen_actions, *args):
    # is this the simplest logical way of expressing this?
    if act_g not in seen_actions and act_wid in seen_actions:
        parser.error('not g, so not wid')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

In this example I save and test for the presence of the action objects.  Testing could also be done using the `dest` strings.  I'm exploring ways of making this testing more intuitive and user friendly.  An expanded set of decorators seems most promising.

Comment: The main point of checking arguments in argparse is to have a nice, helpful, and uniform automated error reporting (otherwise just follow EAFP). Doing it by hand sort of defeats the purpose. Also, as I mentioned, I am talking about a sub-command here, so `parse_args()` is called in a totally different module. Of course this is surmountable, but I find it cludgy.

Comment: I've used custom actions to solve my particular problem, but the solution is relatively complex (for example, it involves setting/clearing .required in actions returned by .add_argument()) and I do not like it much. In most cases what you are proposing is the most sensible approach, so I am accepting your answer.